# When a variable holds a function, why does it get automatically executed PHP

Tags: php, variables

Consider the following:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Why does this get executed? I could understand if i wrote this:

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

And it got executed? but isn't the point of a variable to "hold" stuff, not execute them? Am i way off the mark here?

Comment: You're sooooo off the mark :)

Comment: Thanks thirtydot, feel like a prized lemon now

Comment: How could you *use* return values otherwise?

Comment: When you call a function, it is simply executed, no mistery in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you execute

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

the output of the function is lost, wich is not good in the most cases ;-)

So you want to save the output of a function in a variable. And the operator for this is  "=".

You should consider, that by typing

```
$x = 1 + 1;
```

you want $x = 2; and not "1+1" as a string, wich is basicaly the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

Works as designed: `$result` is assigned the *result* of the `mysql_query()` operation, which you call.

What you want is probably passing the function itself, like JavaScript allows:

```
function x() { alert("Hi"); }

window.onload = x;

window.onload();  // will alert "Hi"
```

this would be possible using something like this (pre-PHP 5.3):

```
$result = create_function("\$sql", "mysql_query(\$sql);");
```

or in PHP 5.3:

```
$result = function($sql) { mysql_query(\$sql); }
```

you can in both cases call the created function:

```
$result($sql);
```

the practice of passing functions around is much, much less common in PHP than it is in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically done when the function returns a value.

The later statement will execute successfully but you cannot utilize the data tat is retrieved.

The 1st statement listed returns the result set as per the execution of the query and assign it to the $result variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `mysql_query($sql);`, it gets executed and it returns a value. In this case the value is not catched, so it get lost. If you write `$result = mysql_query($sql);` it gets executed and the return value is catched. Thats the way a function in every language (even in JS) works.

If you want to "save" a function, than you can use something like

```
$fct = 'mysql_query';
$result = $fct($sql);
```

or in PHP > 5.3 you can use closures, which allows you to set the value also

```
$fct = function () use ($sql) {
    return mysql_query($sql);
}
$result = $fct();
```